# Is it possible to split a cell into multiple rows matching a certain delimiter in Knime?

Tags: excel, split, cell, knime

im knew to using Knime and and want to split a cell whenever the "&" symbol is between the different environments like in input-table below:

Input:

| name | environment |
| --- | --- |
| Thomas Müller | DEV2 & TEST |
| Edward Musk | DEV2 & TEST |
| Franz Hoffmann | DEV2 |

Output

| header 1 | environment |
| --- | --- |
| Thomas Müller | DEV2 |
| Thomas Müller | TEST |
| Edward Musk | DEV2 |
| Edward Musk | TEST |
| Franz Hoffmann | DEV2 |

I know how to split those into mulitple columns using the Cell Splitter and setting the "&" as a delimiter. But I dont want multiple columns, I want the cell splitted into multiple rows. An extra criteria is, that all the uneffected rows (like the 5th one in the outputtable) are unaffected and have the same value es before.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What is `knime`? Do you want to do it by excel formula?

Comment: Does the linked answer help? If not, let us know, we can then re-open.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `knime`. If you want excel formula solution then could try.

```
=LAMBDA(unPivotCol,adjacentCols,DROP(REDUCE(0,REDUCE(0,unPivotCol,LAMBDA(a,x,VSTACK(a,CONCAT(CHOOSEROWS(adjacentCols,ROW(x)-1)&"|")&TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(x,,"&"))))),LAMBDA(p,q,VSTACK(p,TEXTSPLIT(q,"|")))),2))(B2:B4,A2:A4)
```

[image]